# Defining Reusable CDI beans in same container

Tags: java, jsf, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi

I have several CDI bean controllers, that I would like to reuse within my desktop web applications, and mobile web applications (herein called web-components).

Scenario:

I have one Java EE application (EAR)

- I have a web.war component (to refer to the desktop web application)
- I have a mobile.war component (to refer to the mobile web application)

I dont want to use responsive design on the main web application because of how it was designed, so I simply need to develop a mobile version, to be accessed at a different subdomain

```
 m.mydomain.com
```

My intention is to create reusable-component.jar to contain all the CDI controllers, and then include this JAR to the web components.

However, this fails `Jboss weld` detects the same name for the bean, `weld error 00414`

However, I have defined some generic request processing lifecycle on this CDI beans e.g.

```
@OnRequest()
@Named
@RequestScope
public class MyBeanController{
}
```

The `@OnRequest` is a lifecycle callback I have defined, which does a lot of things, including permissions to certain resources which are defined externally in a configuration file.

What I have thought about.

Remove the `@Named` and scope annotations in the `reusable-component.jar`, and then extend them separately on the different web-components.

Problem, I have several cdi beans, quite a lot because this is a huge applications, and extending each of them in the web-component will be a lot of refactoring.

My question:

How can I manage to reuse this CDI beans, in this web-components?

FYI: I have looked at the alternative/stereotype, specialization scenarios, this will still require me to extends all the beans anyway, and my `@OnRequest` annotation lifecycle processing does a bean lookup using the `@Named` or bean name (as specified in cdi), so if I were to use specialization or alternatives, how will this lookup be affected?

Comment: CDI based shared library in EAR with multiple WARs = horror. Related blog: http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2013/10/cdi-behaved-unexpectedly-in-ear-so.html

Comment: @BalusC So, in this case, what option would you suggest? Will implementing different alternatives in the different web-components work?

Answer (score -1):

What I recommend to most people in this scenario is to define two separate WARs and a common JAR.  Include that common JAR within both WARs (as WEB-INF/lib entry).  While the JAR is duplicated, the code is not duplicated.

Comment: Uh, OP is already doing that. Or do you mean two independent WARs without an EAR?

Comment: Looks like the OP is using an EAR.